# FFMPEG: Get video and audio stream from different devices

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 machine with a connected video camera. The video camera is connected to the PC with a magewell HDMI-USB3 converter. On the same PC a microphone is connected via the analog microphone slot.

When I call arecord-l I get the following audio devices:

```
arecord -l

**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (CAPTURE) **** Karte 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]   Sub-Geräte: 1/1  
> Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0 Karte 2: XI100DUSBHDMI [XI100DUSB-HDMI],
> Gerät 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]   Sub-Geräte: 1/1   Sub-Gerät #0:
> subdevice #0
```

I try to create a flv video stream and send it to a nginx web server with the rtmp plugin using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1280x720 -threads 0 -f flv rtmp://192.168.0.36/live/test
```

I am now able to stream the video.

Now I also want to mix the audio sound to the video by sending the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:1 -f video4linux2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1280x720 -threads 0 -ar 11025 -f flv rtmp://192.168.0.36/live/test
```

But now unfortunately I get only the audio sound from the alsa device, but I can see no video stream

Now I tried to write the stream only to a file instead of sending it to a ramp server:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:1 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 out.mpg
```

If I start the file now with a media player, I get the audio and video.

How do I have to change my FFMPEG parameters to stream both: audio and video device input to a new flv stream?

As I mentioned above, the command line call

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:1 -f video4linux2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1280x720 -threads 0 -ar 11025 -f flv rtmp://192.168.0.36/live/test
```

is only encoding and streaming the audio sound, but not the video.

Comment: Try swapping the stream order.

Comment: Show the complete console output from your last `ffmpeg` command.